# Inaccessible variable from locals() after "exec" function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python file "test.py" with code inside:

```
    variable = 10
```

Open python3 and enter next code:

```
    def main():
        with open("test.py") as f:
            exec(f.read())
        print(locals())
        print(variable)
    main()
```

And get output:

```
{'f': <_io.BufferedReader name='test.py'>, 'variable': 10}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in main
NameError: name 'variable' is not defined
```

Why locals() has "variable", but don't able executable it?

Comment: Are you able to access it by doing `locals()['variable']`? If not, shift the `print(variable)` call to inside the `with` block and try if that changes anything?

Comment: ``variable`` should will load from file.

Comment: Yes, I able to access to locals()['variable']

Comment: Since the other file is a python file (`test.py`), it is better practice to import it rather than to `exec` it.

Comment: I know "import" is better that "exec", but my question why locals() has "variable", but don't able executable it

Comment: Interestingly, this is running when not enclosed by a method. I initially thought it might be because both the method and file were named `f`, but that doesn't seem to be the cause.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue (with python 3.6.7)

Comment: I reproduced this issue in Linux with python 3.6.7

Answer (score 1):

OK. Here is my explanation. If you will use the dis module, you will see the following:

```
 32 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (print)
 34 LOAD_GLOBAL              4 (variable)
 36 CALL_FUNCTION            1
```

**LOAD_GLOBAL** - Loads the global named co_names[namei] onto the stack.

But why doesn't the python try to search first in the local namespace? I think this is due to python optimization. 
If done:

```
print(main.__code__.co_varnames)
print(main.__code__.co_names)
```

Can see:

```
('f',)
('open', 'exec', 'read', 'print', 'variable')
```

In this way is the interpreter at compile time into bytecode, sees that there is no such variable in the local scope and generates code to search the global scope. But at the same time, the values ​​for the variables themselves are taken from the locals and globals and `exec` update exactly locals scope, adding there value for `variable`

Answer (score -2):

This will work

```
def f():
    with open("temp.py") as f:
        temp = f.read()
    exec(temp)
    print(locals())
    print(variable)
f()
```

### Explanation

Python works with nested scope, Where any variable defined in outer scope becomes automatically available in the inner scope, but the reverse is not true.

When you are using `exec` within the scope of `with`, the variable `variable` is going to be available only within that scope. it will not be available in the scope of the function `f()` which is outside the scope of the `with` block

Comment: It isn't working for me. Did you run this and check?

Comment: It isn't working for me too. 
Ok, if ```variable``` is outside the scope of the ```with``` block, why locals has ```variable```?

Comment: Your explanation is complete nonsense. Scope in Java works that way, but in python it doesn't - as evident by the fact that you can define your `temp` variable in the with statement scope and access it from outside. You can easily test this by executing `with open("somefile") as f: exec("x=1")` in a script or repl and then printing `x`.